# jquery accordion header index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, accordion

jquery accordion

I like to get the index of the h3 within the "xaccordion".
Just one link in the accordion will have the class "active" (can also be an id, but I made it an class)

How do I get the index. now the element is not fount and the index is returning -1;

**HTML:**

```
<div id="xaccordion">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <a class="active" href="#">link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var active_header = $("#xaccordion a.active").closest("h3");
var active_header_index = $("#xaccordion").index(active_header);

console.log("index: " + active_header_index);
```

Comment: Why have you got a bunch of code inside an H3 element? And you haven't closed it properly - this is a bit of a mess actually - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I forgot to add text to the headers. Basically I want the get the index of the H3. my reference is the a.active below in the dom. Also this html is rendered by javascript. in the source I only have <div id="xaccordion"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your HTML a bit, just so everything is closed:

```
<div id="xaccordion">
    <h3> test </h3>
    <div>
        <p>
          <a href="#">link</a>
          <a href="#">link</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3> test2 </h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            <a href="#">link</a>
            <a href="#">link</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3> test3 </h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            <a href="#">link</a>
            <a class="active" href="#">link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You don't actually need `.closest()` in this case. The way you constructed the HTML you can go up two `.parent()` This will bring you to the div containing the links. From there you need to look for `#xaccordion div`. This will find the index of that `div`. From there you could find the sibling H3, but it's not needed since those indexes will be the same.

Here's the JS:

```
var active_header = $("#xaccordion a.active").parent().parent();
var active_header_index = $("#xaccordion div").index(active_header);

console.log(active_header);
console.log("index: " + active_header_index);
```

Try moving the `class="active"`. This should give the result you're after.

edit: 
here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rc8ack29/

Comment: Thanks. for the feedback but it is still returning -1. The html is rendered by javascript. it is not declared in the source/template.

Comment: This shoudn't matter when the elements are in the DOM. Are you calling the Javascript after the HTML is rendered?

Comment: I fixed it with the counter I already had in my function. The counter was for giving the panel sections and unique id. I prefer the index approach  it's a lot cleaner and saver. I will take another look in my code to fix it. for now it's working. thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Would you tagging an answer so the question doesnt get lost among the rest of unanswered questions.

Comment: I overlooked the div in "#xaccordion div".
I still was using "#xaccordion" Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this code .. hope it works ... made some changes i.e close  tag etc.

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          var active_header = $("a.active").parents("h3").index();
        //var active_header_index = $("#xaccordion").index(active_header);

          console.log(active_header);
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="xaccordion">
  <h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <a class="active" href="#">link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  </h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
        </body>
</html>
```